# Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected

Tags: java, class, syntax, processing

I have 2 tabs on my Processing program. I actually copied and pasted the exact code from a YouTube tutorial and keep getting the error message when I run.

**Tab 1:**

```java
class Bubble {    

float x;
float y;

Bubble (){
  x=width/2;
  y=height; 
}

void ascend (){
  y--;
}

void display() {
  stroke(0);
  fill(127); 
  ellipse(x,y,64,64); 
  }      
}
```

**Tab2:**

```java
Bubble b; 

void setup() {
  size(640,360); 
  b=new Bubble();
}

void draw () {
  background(255); 
  b.ascend();
  b.display();
  //b.top();
}
```

The error message says that:

```
Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. What are the names of your tabs? Have you tried switching the order of your tabs?

Comment: Hi, I didn't know the order of the tab mattered... my first tab is named class and the second tab as function..

Comment: how do I know how to order the tab??

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused because of the absence of `package` declaration.

Comment: @puggo If you're using the Processing editor, you can't reorder the tabs yourself, you'll have to recreate them. Pretty sure functions like `setup()` and `draw()` need to be in the first tab.

Comment: @MohammedDeifallah Processing does not use packages.

Comment: im so confused. so I tried making a new file on processing with just the order of the two code switched and it worked. no idea why... can anybody explain :(

Comment: @KevinWorkmanah so any tab with function has to come frist! thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing functions like `setup()` and `draw()` need to be in the first tab.

I'm not totally sure why this is. It shouldn't be strictly necessary because all of the tabs get converted into one Java file, unless your tab names ends with `.java`. My guess is this is a quirk of the Processing -> Java compiler.

You could file a bug on the [Processing GitHub repo](https://github.com/processing/processing), but I think your best bet is to make sure all your Processing functions are in the first tab.